# How to get items in a custom list using SuiteTalk

Tags: netsuite

I want to set the value of a custom customer field. The field type is List/Record and the value must be from a custom list.

I believe I have to set the value to the internal ID value of the custom list item. The items look like this:
[image]

Am I right that I have to use the ID value? Instead could I set the customer field to the Value value?

Assuming that I have to set the customer field to the ID value, I want to load all the items into memory and then look up the ID by the Value, like this:
[image]

The problem is that I cannot work out how to download the items using SuiteTalk. I can use CustomListSearchBasic to get the custom list record:
[image]

But I can't seem to get the items in the custom list.

Please can you help? Also, I'd be delighted to know how to work this out for myself. The schema browser didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked it out. I needed to set searchPreferences.bodyFieldsOnly = false